# Solving $b^e = 1 \mod m$ for $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, computational-mathematics

I would like to find small $b$ such that
$$
b^e\equiv1\pmod m
$$
for a given $e$ and $m$. (In my application, $m$ is the square of a prime.) How can I find such $b$? (Say, the first 10 or 100.)

I'm interested in something practical for $e$ with 10-20 digits and $m$ with 20-40 digits.

Feel free to close this as a duplicate if you can find the right question!

Comment: Probably hard to find small $b$ with this property, for general $e.$ Even the case $e=2$ seems to require a prime factorization of $m,$ and even then seems to require you to compute most of the $2^k$ different values, where $k$ is the number of prime factors of $m.$

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler's theorem: $b^{\phi(m)}=1 \pmod m, \gcd(b,m)=1$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have a factorization of $m$ (and for $m$ so small, it's not hard to factor it without knowledge). For this particular application, $m=p^2$ for a prime $p$.

Comment: You should add the $m=p^2$ comment to the question, that greatly reduces the question. But I’m still suspicious that there wont be a good solution other than enumerating most values

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I did mention it in the question, though I am also interested in the general composite case.

Comment: For the case $m=p^2$, $\phi(m)=p^2 \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$. More generally $\phi(m)=m \prod_{p|m} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$. If $gcd(b,m)\ne 1$ there is no solution. If $gcd(b,m)=1$ then $e=\phi(m)$ is always a solution, and sometimes divisors of $\phi(m)$ are also a solution.

Comment: @StevenClark $m$ and $e$ are given, not $b$.

Comment: Let me give an example with small numbers. Say $m=19^2$ and $e=18$. Then the $b$ that work are 1, 28, 54, 62, 68, 69, 99, 116, 127, 234, 245, 262, 292, 293, 299, 307, 333, 360 mod $19^2$.

Comment: For $m=19^2=361$, $\phi(m)=342$ and $342=18\times19$, so $e=18$ will work for some but not all values of $b$ where $gcd(b,361)=1$. All divisors of $342$ have some solutions, but $e=342$ works for every $b$ where $gcd(b,361)=1$.

Comment: @StevenClark The whole question is: how to find the (small instances of) "some but not all" when $m$ and $e$ are relatively large?

Comment: My point is that first you need to understand the necessary conditions for $b^e\equiv1\pmod m$. You can't just select random values of $e$ and $m$ and expect to find solutions.

Comment: @StevenClark I do, and the given $m$ and $e$ meet the conditions. (If they didn't, the question would be trivial: no solutions exist.) I'm just trying to find the possible values of $b$ when $m$ is too large to checking all values.

Comment: I kinda want to be cheeky and say that the answer is always $1$, but seriously, I can't really think of a way to make this simpler than iterating over possible values of $b$. It's the same difficulty as finding the order mod $m$, and I don't think we have tools much better than iteration for that.----Of course there are some "common sense" things to note. $b^e>p^2 \implies \log_b e>2log_b p$, so small bases require larger exponents in general. You can skip checking $b=2$ for any $e$ with fewer bits than $p$, etc.